# SQL Server 2005 table too big

Tags: sql, sql-server, bigdata

I have this table.

I don't know why this table is too big.

This is the table structure.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACI_HISCLI](
    [TER_CODI] [varchar](13) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [HIS_NUME] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HIS_FECH] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HIS_ESTA] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [HIS_HORA] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MED_CODI] [decimal](13, 0) NOT NULL,
    [HIS_HOEN] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [HIS_HODC] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [HIS_MOTI] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_AODS] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_AODC] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_AOSS] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_AOSC] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ODQ1] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ODQ2] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_ODQ3] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ODQ4] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_OSQ1] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OSQ2] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_OSQ3] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OSQ4] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_ODR1] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ODR2] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ODR3] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_OSR1] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OSR2] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OSR3] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_ODS1] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ODS2] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ODS3] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_ODS4] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OSS1] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OSS2] [decimal](4, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OSS3] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_OSS4] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ADI1] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_ADI2] [varchar](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ADI3] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_TON1] [datetime] NULL,
    [HIS_TOOD] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_TOOS] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_MOVI] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIOM] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_FOJO] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OTRO] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [DIA_COD1] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [DIA_COD2] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [DIA_COD3] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_COND] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OBSE] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_IMA1] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_IMN1] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_IMA2] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_IMN2] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_CONS] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ORIL] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ORIT] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ORIP] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_INGS] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_INGA] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_INGC] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_INGE] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_INGL] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_TAIN] [varchar](7) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_PUIN] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_TEIN] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_TAEG] [varchar](7) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_PUEG] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_TEEG] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_OBHE] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [USU_CREA] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [HIS_ASPR] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [PRO_CONS] [int] NULL,
    [MED_CODC] [decimal](13, 0) NULL,
    [ANE_CODI] [decimal](13, 0) NULL,
    [AYU_CODI] [decimal](13, 0) NULL,
    [INS_CODI] [decimal](13, 0) NULL,
    [HIS_DIPR] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIPO] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DECI] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_GODV] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_GODT] [varchar](200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_GOIV] [int] NULL,
    [HIS_GOIT] [varchar](200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIFO] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIOT] [varchar](51) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OBSD] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OBSS] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ODLA] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_ODFR] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_OILA] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_OIFR] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_ODSE] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_OISE] [image] NULL,
    [HIS_GOD1] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD2] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD3] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD4] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD5] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD6] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD7] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOD8] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI1] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI2] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI3] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI4] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI5] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI6] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI7] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_GOI8] [decimal](3, 2) NULL,
    [HIS_CONT] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_RESU] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_GLIC] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_HEMA] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_PAQU] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_CREA] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_ELEC] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIO1] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIO2] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIO3] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIO4] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_BIO5] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OBEX] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_OBST] [varchar](150) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIT1] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIT2] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIT3] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_TANE] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ENT_CODI] [numeric](13, 0) NULL,
    [HIS_DIDR] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIDO] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIPI] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DISA] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIO1] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIO2] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_DIO3] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HIS_HOAN] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_NOAC] [varchar](120) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_TACO] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_PACO] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_DACO] [varchar](70) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_IACO] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_NORE] [varchar](120) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_TRES] [varchar](25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_PRES] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_DRES] [varchar](70) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TER_IRES] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [USU_AUDI] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [FEC_AUDI] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TIP_AUDI] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [MOD_ORIG] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**with the command `sp_spaceued ACI_HISCLI`**

this is the result:

```
name: ACI_HISCLI
rows: 270719
reserved:   64521288 KB
data:       64377992 KB
index_size:      152 Kb
unused:       143144 KB
```

the fields of type image, almost are null.
This table have so much transactions for the users but is only text ant the size is 60 GB !!
I dont know why this table is so big !.
How can optimize this table or shrink this table.
Im try with :

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE
```

and rebuild the index
Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT index_id,type_desc,total_pages,used_pages,data_pages FROM sys.partitions p INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id WHERE p.object_id = object_id('[dbo].[ACI_HISCLI]')`

Comment: can you please provide any PK and /or index definitions or is this a heap? And what version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of those TEXT and IMAGE fields take up 16 bytes each as they are pointers to where the data really resides (when there is data there).  But I am almost certain that just like fixed-width datatypes (INT, BIGINT, DATETIME, etc.) they take up that space even when NULL.

Also, the table really has too many fields to be manageable.  You should consider breaking it up into two (or more) tables that have the same PK, are FKed together, and have a 1-to-1 relationship.  Fields that are not used that often should be moved to the secondary table.

EDIT:
The data-space used is also affected by the FILLFACTOR setting on the Clustered Index.  Setting it too low, especially with such a large row-size, will cause very few rows to fit on the 8k datapage.

Also, sometimes space is not released when rows are deleted.  Doing an index REBUILD on the Clustered Index would release that space (you will know if there was unreleased space after doing the REBUILD if the size drops quite a bit).

EDIT2:
Anyone using SQL Server 2005 and newer should look to convert fields using the old blob types (which are now deprecated) to the newer equivalents:

- TEXT -> VARCHAR(MAX)
- NTEXT -> NVARCHAR(MAX)
- IMAGE -> VARBINARY(MAX)

Comment: Even if each of the 270,719 rows was using a full 8KB page that would "only" be 2 GB though. They must be using a lot of row overflow or LOB space.

Comment: @Martin,   I wasn't saying that they were the entire space, just that they can't be discounted when NULL.  Quite likely heavy usage of the text fields, but I assumed the OP had some knowledge of what data is in them.

Comment: Added +1 I can split that table putting all nullable columns in another tables and (a great maybe here) move all that blobs (images) out of the DB.

Comment: @jean, what version of SQL Server are you using?  There are several other things to consider, depending on what version is being used.

Comment: Jean isn't the OP. The title states 2005 though.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I know that jean isn't the OP, but based on what the person said it seemed reasonable to suspect that they were working together. Thanks for pointing out the title, not sure how I missed that outside of being sleep-deprived ;-)

Comment: @srutzky - And I missed the "I can split that table". It does come across like that :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith, it was that part as well as the "a great maybe here" that made me think there was personal involvement. So the language but with a different user name is ambiguous so I just picked the interpretation that I liked ;-).